# como modificar el tabwidget para que tenga dos hileras en vez de scrollbuttons?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

quiero que mi ventana se vea como esta 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probé revisando la documentación de QTabWidget y QTabBar y no hay forma directa. Lo maximo que permite hacer una subclase de QTabBar es personalizar el tamaño de cada tab, mas no su posición. Finalmente, tampoco hay una forma usando stylesheets. Probablemente, haya que crear un widget personalizado para lograr lo planteado.